# Magento SOAP API v2 shoppingCartProductAdd error “One item of products do not have identifier or sku”

Tags: .net, vb.net, magento

I'm getting "One item of products do not have identifier or sku" error when attempting to submit shoppingCartProductAdd API request

I'm submitting both a valid SKU and Product_ID.  So the error doesn't make sense to me.

Here's some of the relevant code…

```
Dim pendingCartItems As New List(Of shoppingCartProductEntity)
        If qtyAustin > 0 Then
            Dim ticketRequest As New shoppingCartProductEntity
            ticketRequest.sku = "RH_00001"
            ticketRequest.product_id = "2"
            ticketRequest.qty = qtyAustin
            pendingCartItems.Add(ticketRequest)
        End If

        AddToCart(pendingCartItems)


        Public Sub AddToCart(ByVal cartItems As List(Of shoppingCartProductEntity))
            mClient.shoppingCartProductAdd(mSession, mCart, cartItems.ToArray(), mStore)
        End Sub
```

API documentation for shoppingCartProductAdd:  http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html

Comment: What's mClient? Can you perhaps post additional relevant code?

Comment: Which API method you have used for this ?

Comment: What is your endpoint URL?

Answer (score 0):

First you have enabled the [WS-I compliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Services_Interoperability) in Magento

```
Magento admin -> System -> Configuration -> Services -> Magento Core API
```

then set "`WS-I Compliance`" to "`yes`".

Get the WSDL with WS-I compliance from your host

```
http://mymagentohost/index.php/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1
```

Configure the SOAP/XML-RPC users and roles from

```
Magento admin -> System -> Web Services -> SOAP/XML-RPC-Users & SOAP/XML-RPC-Roles
```

and set permissions.

Now you can generate your client Proxy classes (Axis, Axis2, Microsoft WSDL tool... etc)

Check your endpoint URL, it should be

```
http://mymagentohost/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/
```

My functional testing code using Axis2

```
package magento;

import java.rmi.RemoteException;

import magento.MagentoServiceStub.EndSessionParam;
import magento.MagentoServiceStub.LoginParam;
import magento.MagentoServiceStub.LoginResponseParam;
import magento.MagentoServiceStub.ShoppingCartCreateRequestParam;
import magento.MagentoServiceStub.ShoppingCartCreateResponseParam;
import magento.MagentoServiceStub.ShoppingCartProductAddRequestParam;
import magento.MagentoServiceStub.ShoppingCartProductAddResponseParam;
import magento.MagentoServiceStub.ShoppingCartProductEntity;
import magento.MagentoServiceStub.ShoppingCartProductEntityArray;

import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MagentoServiceStub stub = new MagentoServiceStub();

            LoginParam loginParam = new LoginParam();
            loginParam.setUsername("myuser");
            loginParam.setApiKey("1b6bf41e547e06b5b795d44b2f8f8f54");
            LoginResponseParam p = stub.login(loginParam);
            String sessionId = p.getResult();

            ShoppingCartCreateRequestParam createParam = new ShoppingCartCreateRequestParam();
            createParam.setSessionId(sessionId);
            //param2.setStore("1");
            ShoppingCartCreateResponseParam resp = stub.shoppingCartCreate(createParam);
            int sr = resp.getResult();

            ShoppingCartProductAddRequestParam prodcutAddParam = new ShoppingCartProductAddRequestParam();
            prodcutAddParam.setSessionId(sessionId);
            prodcutAddParam.setQuoteId(sr);
            ShoppingCartProductEntityArray array = new ShoppingCartProductEntityArray(); 
            ShoppingCartProductEntity producto = new ShoppingCartProductEntity();
            producto.setSku("prueba");
            producto.setQty(1);
            array.addComplexObjectArray(producto);
            prodcutAddParam.setProductsData(array);

            ShoppingCartProductAddResponseParam prodAddResult = stub.shoppingCartProductAdd(prodcutAddParam);
            System.out.println("product added? " + prodAddResult.getResult());

            EndSessionParam endSessionParam = new EndSessionParam();
            endSessionParam.setSessionId(sessionId);

            stub.endSession(endSessionParam);

        } catch (AxisFault e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Hope this helps you.