# Magento SOAP API and PHP: One item of products do not have identifier or sku

Tags: php, api, magento, soap

Good Day, need help on this scenario. We have a client who has a Magento ver 1.9 system which I don't have access. They have asked us to create a mobile app and we are using as PHP Laravel 5.1 as a proxy rest api to call Magento's SOAP API V2. One of the services was to add a product to the cart. I've used this reference http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/checkout/cartProduct/cart_product.add.html but unfortunately when I call the service I'm getting this error

```
"One item of products do not have identifier or sku"
```

Here is the snippet of the php code:

```
$data = array_add($data, 'product_id', $request->json('product_id'));
$data = array_add($data, 'sku', $request->json('sku'));
$data = array_add($data, 'qty', $request->json('qty'));
$data = array_add($data, 'options', $request->json('options'));
$data = array_add($data, 'bundleOption', $request->json('bundleOption'));
$data = array_add($data, 'bundleOptionQty', $request->json('bundleOptionQty'));
$data = array_add($data, 'links', $request->json('links'));

try {
    $result = $client->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId,$cartId,$data);

    if ($result) {
        return $this->respond([
            'message' => 'Product Successfully added to Cart.'
        ]);
    }

} catch (SoapFault $e) {
    $message = $e->getMessage();
    return $this->respondInternalError($message);
}
```

Here is the Json request

```
{"product_id":"13","sku":"Warm-Welcome-Coat","qty":"5","options":"","bundleOption":"","bundleOptionQty":"","links":""}
```

I'm sure that the product is existing as I used the api to call the product list. I've tried this solution -> [Magento SOAP API v2 shoppingCartProductAdd error “One item of products do not have identifier or sku”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21756352/magento-soap-api-v2-shoppingcartproductadd-error-one-item-of-products-do-not-ha) but it is not working for me.

Comment: can  you please share your codes ? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved in this problem. It seems that the format of my data array is incorrect as the sample from the Magento states that:

```
$result = $proxy->shoppingCartProductAdd($sessionId, 10, array(array(
'product_id' => '4',
'sku' => 'simple_product',
'qty' => '5',
'options' => null,
'bundle_option' => null,
'bundle_option_qty' => null,
'links' => null
)));
```

While the $data from my example is just an array.